# Chain rule with total and partial derivatives.

Tags: matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Let $g: \mathbb{R}^{N_\ell \times N_{\ell-1}} \to \mathbb{R}^{N_\ell} \;\;\;$  $g(W) = Wa$
a function that takes a matrix as an argument, and multiplies it by a vector $a \in \mathbb{R}^{N_\ell}$

Let $h: \mathbb{R}^{N_\ell} \to \mathbb{R} \;$ a differentiable function

I want to differentiate the composition $h \circ g$ with respect to the matrix $W$, so I differentiate with respect to each of its components. I want to use the total derivative of h, and my intuition says that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_{j,i}}(h \circ g) 
                = Dh \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial W^\ell_{j,i}}$ where Dh is the total derivative of h, and $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial W^\ell_{j,i}}$ is the partial derivative of g with respect to the j-row i-column component of the matrix $W$

My questions are: is my intuition correct? If so, why is it? (I'm familiar with the chain rule of total derivatives, but I've never seen it mixed with partial derivatives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it's ok. You can do the same calculation different ways.

### In index notation.

Writing $n=N_\ell$ and $m=N_{\ell-1}$,
$$\begin{align}
\partial_{ij}(h\circ g)
&= \sum_k (\partial_k h\circ g)\partial_{ij} g_k \\
&=
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_1h\circ g & \cdots & \partial_nh\circ g
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_{ij}g_1 \\
\vdots \\
\partial_{ij}g_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$
As you wanted.

Now, for your specific problem since $g_k(W)=\sum_r W_{kr}a_r$, you have $\partial_{ij}g_k=\delta_{ik}a_j$, so your derivative is
$$\begin{align}
\partial_{ij}(h\circ g)
&= \sum_k (\partial_k h\circ g)\partial_{ij} g_k \\
&= \sum_k (\partial_k h\circ g)\delta_{ik}a_j \\
&= a_j(\partial_i h\circ g).
\end{align}$$

### In differential notation

This is also nice. Taking $\nabla h$ as a row vector and $a$ as a column vector
$$\begin{align}
d(h(Wa))
&= \nabla h(Wa):d(Wa) \\
&= \nabla h(Wa):dWa \\
&= dWa:\nabla h(Wa) \\
&= dW:a\nabla h(Wa) \\
\end{align}$$
so that
$$
\frac{dh(Wa)}{dW} = a\nabla h(Wa).
$$

### By definition of the derivative

The derivative of a function $f$ at $W$ is a linear operator $Df(W)$ such that
$$
f(W+H) - f(W) = Df(W)(H)
$$
for any infinitesimal matrix $H$. You can also say it in terms of limits or using the big $O$ notation, but this way is easier in notation.
Now take $f(W)=h(Wa)$, so that
Ignoring terms of higher order in $H$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(W+H) - f(W)
&= -h(Wa) + h(Wa+Ha) \\
&= -h(Wa) + h(Wa) + Dh(Wa)(Ha) \\
&= Dh(Wa)(Ha) \\
&= \nabla h(Wa)Ha \\
&= \nabla h(Wa):Ha \\
&= Ha:\nabla h(Wa) \\
&= H:a\nabla h(Wa) \\
&= a\nabla h(Wa):H.
\end{align}
$$
The term $a\nabla h(Wa):H$ is linear in $H$, so this should be $Df(W)(H)$.
$$
Df(W)(H) = a\nabla h(Wa):H.
$$